# Trim last 4 characters of Object

Tags: java, string, oop, object, substring

I want to trim last 4 charaters of Object Displayed in 3rd `(Room Type)` and 4th (`Meal type)` column. as in the bottom i have provided the sample of output. You can clearly  see in 3rd and 4th column the last 4 characters are price in bracket, which i want to trip.

```
public void showAll()

    {
        String name ="";
        String ID="";
        Object roomItem;
        Object mealItem;
        int roomIn;
        int meal;
        int days=0;
        double tprice=0;

        display.setText("");
        display.append("ID  Customer Name   RoomType    MealType    Days    TotalCharge($)");
        display.append("\n ---------------------------------");

        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
           {
        Customer c = myList.get(i);

        ID = c.getID();
        name = c.getName();
        roomIn = c.getRoomIndex();                  // Get the room index stored in Linked list
        roomItem = roomTypeCombo.getItemAt(roomIn); // Get the item stored on that index.
        meal = c.getMealIndex();                    // Get the Meal index stored in Linked list
        mealItem = mealCombo.getItemAt(meal);       // Get the item stored on that index.
        days = c.getDaysIndex();
        tprice = c.getTotalPrice();
        display.append("\n"+ID+"    "+name+"        "+roomItem+"    "+mealItem+"    "+days+ "   "+tprice);
            }
        display.append("\n \n Total "+myList.size()+" Entrie(s) !");

    } // end of function
```

And output of my program is like this:

```
ID  Customer Name           RoomType    MealType    Days    TotalCharge
__________________________________________________________________

234 John Andersen       Standard($75)   Any Two($30)     4    420.0
```

how can i trip last 4 characters of `Room Type` and `Meal Type`?

Comment: Did you have a look at the Java API? There's a method defined for `String`: `subString(...)`. I'll leave the parameters for you to figure out - it's not that hard with some reading.

Comment: @Thomas: I have tried substring() but RoomItem and MealItem are declared as Object not a string. so when i am trying to use substring it is showing that "Cannot find a symbol" error.

Comment: @Ravi well, what is the _exact_ type of `roomItem`? It can't be `Object` but must be a subtype. If it`s `String` then, well ... did you hear of casting?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes i know, but when i defined roomItem as a string, it was not storing my result and getting error then i searched for it and came with result that i need to define as Object.

Answer (score 2):

```
String pricey = "Breakfast($10)";
String yummy = pricey.substring(0, pricey.length() - 4);
```

Comment: As per Javadoc, it would be a good idea to see that `pricey.length() - 4` will not yield a negative value since this will cause an exception.

Comment: @npinti - Good point. A general-purpose string-shortening method should either do that check or specify in the method docs that passing a string shorter than 4 characters will throw an exception.

Comment: But my roomItem is declared as Object instead of String.

Answer (score 1):

First you should read Java String API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html before posting this kind of questions.

Then, you can use something like the substring method.

```
public String substring(int beginIndex,
               int endIndex)

Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

Examples:

     "hamburger".substring(4, 8) returns "urge"
     "smiles".substring(1, 5) returns "mile"


Parameters:
    beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
    endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.
Returns:
    the specified substring.
Throws:
    IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or beginIndex is larger than endIndex.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

```
String word = "Breakfast($10)".substring(0, "Breakfast($10)".length() - 4);
```

Comment: As per Javadoc, it would be a good idea to see that `pricey.length() - 4` will not yield a negative value since this will cause an exception.

Comment: You do have to check the length of the string before you try to take a substring of it, of course.

Comment: Unfortunately, this code will return the last four characters, not everything up to the last four.

Comment: Forgot a 0.  Good catch, @TedHopp!

Comment: But my roomItem variable declared as Object rather than String. substring and length are the String function.

Comment: You never said that in your original question...Instead of using `Object`, create a custom object and have a field in which you can retrieve that String from.  *Then* use `substring()`.  Better yet, change `Object` to `String`.

Comment: @Ravi - You can use `String.valueOf(roomItem)` (or `roomItem.toString()` if you're sure that `roomItem` is not `null`) and then work from that. (That's what is happening anyway when you use the `+` operator in a String expression.)